# Find anti-derivative of hairy expression under radical

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, radicals, substitution

I'm lost on how to pull the anti-derivative of the expression under the radical. The full integral I'm evaluating is:

$$2\pi\int_{16}^{25}(9-{\sqrt{x}})^2{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{9}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2}}dx$$

I think I need to use u-substitution, however I'm not sure what my u should equal.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, and $(\sqrt{x^2})^2 = x^2$. So the expression inside the radical simplifies to $(x^2+81)/x^2$,

Comment: $$\sqrt x=3\tan t$$

Comment: Under radical is $\frac{x+81}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{x}=9\tan{t},$ where $t\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right).$

Thus, $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=\frac{9}{\cos^2t}dt$$ or
$$dx=\frac{162\sin{t}}{\cos^3t}dt.$$

Id est, $$\int\left(9-\sqrt{x}\right)^2\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{9}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2}dx=\int(9-9\tan{t})^2\sqrt{1+\cot^2t}\frac{162\sin{t}}{\cos^3t}dt=$$
$$=13122\int\frac{(1-2\sin{t}\cos{t})\sin{t}}{\cos^2t\sin{t}\cos^3t}dt=13122\left(\int\frac{1}{\cos^5t}dt-2\int\frac{\sin{t}}{\cos^4t}dt\right)=$$
$$=13122\left(\int\frac{1}{(1-\sin^2t)^3}d\sin{t}+2\int\frac{1}{\cos^4t}d\cos{t}\right)=...$$
Can you end it now?